# How to pass data for Bootstraps modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to pass the value of my button to my bootstrap modal and modal is not receiving any data. The button has its data inside but using the same variable for the modal is not working. Here is my code.

```
    <?PHP
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_posts INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_posts.userID = tbl_user.userID WHERE postStatus = 'Show' ORDER BY postDateTime DESC;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
      <div class="container post" style="border: 1px solid black;">
          <h4><?PHP echo $row['userFirstname'] . " " . $row['userLastname'];  ?></h4>
          <p class="time"><?PHP echo time_elapsed_string($row['postDateTime']); ?></p>
          <p class="post"><?PHP echo $row['postDetail'];?></p>
          <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" name="postDetail" value="<?PHP  echo $row['postID'] ?>"><?PHP echo $row['postID']; ?></button>
          <Br>
      </div>
    <?PHP

    ?>

 <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><?PHP  echo $row["postID"]; ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal content-->
  </div>
</div>
  <!-- Modal -->

<?PHP
  }
}

?>
```

The modal is showing but the `<?PHP  echo $row["postID"]; ?>` is showing me only the last row of the database.

Comment: You can get the records by Ajax.

Comment: @Virb - Without ajax i can't solve this problem?

Comment: Your $row["postID"] is out of while loop !!

Comment: And you are using the `$row` variable out of loop

Comment: You can get using `$_GET` but it is unsecured. I recommend to use Ajax with `POST`.

Comment: I tried to put it inside of the while loop but the postID is only getting me the last row.

Comment: You can do one more thing. You can put this bootstrap modal in while loop.so when the loop executes, it will place the values in modal dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your $row is effective in while loop.

if yout want to use only one modal and reuse, you will need to use ajax when click the button.

or move modal section to inside while loop.
pair modal div's id and button's data-target.
**each modal must has different id.** in your case, postID will be good identifier.

```
<?PHP
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_posts INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_posts.userID = tbl_user.userID WHERE postStatus = 'Show' ORDER BY postDateTime DESC;";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        ?>
    <div class="container post" style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <h4><?PHP echo $row['userFirstname'] . " " . $row['userLastname'];  ?></h4>
        <p class="time"><?PHP echo time_elapsed_string($row['postDateTime']); ?></p>
        <p class="post"><?PHP echo $row['postDetail'];?></p>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_<?PHP echo $row['postID']; ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" name="postDetail" value="<?PHP  echo $row['postID'] ?>"><?PHP echo $row['postID']; ?></button>
        <Br>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal_<?PHP echo $row['postID']; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><?PHP  echo $row["postID"]; ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal content-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
<?PHP
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I moved it inside the while loop now. But the value of the row is only giving me the last data of the database even if i click others only one value is showing up

Comment: Oh, so that could be the problem modal ID. Okay sir now i got it! Thank you so much for this! So the problem is as many as my rows is that also is the number of my modal so i will only call the modal that have the same id that i pressed. Thank you so much sir!

Comment: it's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?PHP
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_posts INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_posts.userID = tbl_user.userID WHERE postStatus = 'Show' ORDER BY postDateTime DESC;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
      <div class="container post" style="border: 1px solid black;">
          <h4><?PHP echo $row['userFirstname'] . " " . $row['userLastname'];  ?></h4>
          <p class="time"><?PHP echo time_elapsed_string($row['postDateTime']); ?></p>
          <p class="post"><?PHP echo $row['postDetail'];?></p>
          <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" name="postDetail" value="<?PHP  echo $row['postID'] ?>"><?PHP echo $row['postID']; ?></button>
          <Br>
      </div>
    <?PHP
 }
}
?>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><?PHP  echo $_POST["postID"]; ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal content-->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your button to this:

```
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-my-button" name="postDetail" data-title="<?php  echo $row['postID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['postID']; ?></button>
```

just put the value that you need with the data-* in the button then add jquery with the class of your button.

jquery:

```
$('.btn-my-button').click(function(){
$('#myModal .modal-title').text($(this).data('title'));
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```